# Disable or Set Read only HTML 5 Canvas by jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have to disable a canvas element of html 5 from jquery or javascript through any property.
Is there any way. It should be like only white screen should be visible and user could not draw anything...

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do anything to achieve this. By default Canvas only displays anything if write code to draw on it and users can only draw on it if there is code that allows them to do so. In other words you get what you want just by not writing code to draw on it.

Comment: I believe his intend was a way to disable the drawing stuff, after it was set to on, in a simples and centralized way.

Comment: This is totally not the way that canvas works. The default is that the canvas is enabled.